# index out of range error when looping through a 2d list

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I am trying to loop through a 2d list but i am getting - list index out of range error. if know why please respond or provide any source links that you are aware of. Thank you.
here is the initiation

```
self.Cost_matrix = []
    for i in range(int(self.e.get())):
        
        # self.l10 = Label(self.f4, text = f'Zone {i+1}', bg = '#d9d9d9')
        # self.l10.grid(row=i+2, column=0)

        # self.l11 = Label(self.f4, text = f'Zone {i+1}', bg = '#d9d9d9')
        # self.l11.grid(row=1, column=i+1)
        
        for j in range(int(self.e.get())):
            self.Cost_row = []
            self.e5 = Entry(self.f4, width = 12)
            self.e5.grid(row = i+2, column = j+1)
            self.Cost_row.append(self.e5)
        self.Cost_matrix.append(self.Cost_row)
```

this how i tried to access it

```
for i in range(len(self.Cost_matrix)):
        for j in range(len(self.Cost_matrix)):
            self.impedence_factor = float(self.Cost_matrix[i][j].get())
            print(f'elements of Cost matrix is {self.impedence_factor}')
```

when running this block of code I am getting an error saying that index of self.Cost_matrix[i][j] is out range.

please comment if you know anything regarding this. thank you.

Comment: probably because you are adding 1 to the lengths of the two lists in the for loops

Comment: You are adding 1 to the list of length. So the last element generated in range is out of index for the list

Comment: You need to move `self.Cost_row = []` before `for j in range(...)`.